# Firebase/Firestore: Is it possible to query .where(x == foo || x == bar)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of users, which looks like this:

[image]

Each follower/following document is structured like this:

```
{
  uid: ...,
}
```

I want to create a query that satisfies these criteria:

1. Get the users that you are following
2. Ordered by their 'lastPosted' time (so you're getting the users who have posted most recently first)

Since the follower/following subcollections only contain references to full user documents, and not the full documents themselves, it's not as easy as just querying the following subcollection.

---

This is what I've tried:

```
database
.collection('users')
.doc(myUid)
.collection('following')
.get()
.then(followings => {
  database
  .collection('users')
  .orderBy('lastPosted', 'desc')
  .where('uid', '==', following[0] || following[1] ...)
})
```

Which doesn't work. I have also thought about this:

```
database
.collection('users')
.orderBy('lastPosted', 'desc')
.where(myUid exists in their followers subcollection)
```

---

I'm not sure where to go from here, or whether firestore even allows this.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: Please also add the content of your document to see the properties on which you want to filter.

Comment: @AlexMamo have edited the document structure

Comment: As a screenshot please.

Answer (score 1):

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

> Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.

Comment: Firebase seriously doesn’t have an equivalent to `IN` in SQL?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries . The where() method takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a comparison operation, and a value. The comparison can be <, <=, ==, >, >=, or array_contains. And Collection group queries.

Comment: So that’s a no. Odd.